# Radio button is checked on click event even though preventDefault is ran

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

```js
thing.addEventListener('click', click)

function click(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.target.checked);
}
```

```html
  <input id="thing" type="radio" name="gender">
```

Why is `e.target.checked == true` even though preventDefault is ran and the radio button is not checked?

Answer (score 1):

By the time you call preventDefault, the radio button is already checked. PreventDefault simply undoes this. You can see this if you set a short timeout on the console log.

```js
thing.addEventListener('click', click)

function click(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(e.target.checked);
    }, 10);
}
```

```html
<input id="thing" type="radio" name="gender">
```

Comment: I tried to run e.preventDefault() on both mouseup and mousedown but both still caused the radio button to be checked. Where can I run e.preventDefault() to stop the radio button from getting checked in the first place?

Comment: There does not appear to be any event which fires *before* the `checked` property is updated. The change happens within the native code itself, so all we can do is respond by undoing the change with `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `preventDefault()` removed value from the tag which an event function is fired. But when `after preventDefault()` is fired `e.target.checked` is `false` as below. So finally e.target.checked is false.

```js
thing.addEventListener('click', click)

function click(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    setTimeout(()=> console.log(e.target.checked), 100);
}
```

```html
<input id="thing" type="radio" name="gender">
```